# I'm having trouble with my Apache Server Permissions on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server, osx-yosemite

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to create a login page:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/users/userlist.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Library/WebServer/Documents/register_draft.php on line 17

Warning: file_put_contents(/users/passlist.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Library/WebServer/Documents/register_draft.php on line 18

Warning: file_put_contents(/users/pinlist.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Library/WebServer/Documents/register_draft.php on line 19

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Library/WebServer/Documents/register_draft.php:17) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/register_draft.php on line 20
```

I have created a folder I need to put all the users in called "users" in my /Library/Webserver/Documents/

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$file1 = '/users/userlist.txt';
$file2 = '/users/passlist.txt';
$file3 = '/users/pinlist.txt';
$user = usermail;
$pass = password;
$pin = pi;

$safeUser = testUserInput($user);
$safePass = testUserInput($pass);
$safePin = testUserInput($pin);

if ($safeUser != "unsafe" && $safeUser != "empty" && $safeUser != "spaces") {
if ($safePass != "empty" && $safePass != "unsafe" && $safePass != "spaces") {
    if ($safePin != "empty" && $safePin != "unsafe" && $safePin != "spaces") {
        $hashedPass = password_hash($safePass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        file_put_contents($file1, $safeUser . "<br>", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents($file2, $hashedPass . "<br>", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents($file3, $safePin . "<br>", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        header("Location: ../users"); //change this to direct user to login page, account successfully created
}
}
}     else {
header("Location: ../users"); //change this to direct user back to     registration page with error prompt
}

function testUserInput($x) {
$test = strpbrk($x,"<>/\;()%-+.=,");
if ($test != false) {
    $x = "unsafe";  
} elseif (strlen($x) == 0) {
    $x = "empty";
} elseif (ctype_space($x)) {
    $x = "spaces";
}
return $x;
}
?>
```

If you see any other problems with the code, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: php runs as the _www user normally on OS X, so does _www have write and execute permissions for the relevant directory? Also paths starting with '/' are absolute and refer to root, so you are referring to the /Users directory that OS X uses to store home directories by default, which doesn't seem like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try these please:

1. Run your commands as sudo  whenever you get such messages
2. For your document root, execute:
   sudo chown _www:_www /path_to_docroot/

Please share the results and we can debug further if this does not solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)